# save data on SQL or on the server

Tags: java, android, sql, httprequest

I have been working recently on an app and I reached a crossroad... I am new to this so, you might find my question trivial.

In the app we have a certain data we are using that we have saved in the server, this data is not user specific but, general to all users and is vital for the functionality of the app. This data will be updated from time to time.

So, my question is:

From your experience would it be more practical to save all the data using SQL or to keep the data on the server and keep requesting it frequently?

Comment: How much data? Does it need sorting / searching or other wise manipulated?  If not just a properties file may suffice.

Comment: the data in whole is a round 11mbs but when manipulating its pretty small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, it really depends on what type of data it is.

Since this data is vital for the functionality of your app, that means you should keep the vital portions of the data cached locally in your app. This is to avoid cases where users can't use your app during times when they lose connection to the internet.

So typically, it would be a good idea to store enough data in a local database for users to use your app. But if the data is very sensitive and shouldn't be easily tampered with, then you would want to store it only on your server instead.

But still, it depends on what type of data. If it's data that has no specific need to be on your own servers and it's just meant for the user to use their app, then storing it locally is enough.